# Trying to use NSUInteger with an enum (<<)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, ios

I'm not very good with terminology.. here's the code I have:

```
enum {
    LoggerLogNone        = 0,
    LoggerLogMessages    = 1 << 0,
    LoggerLogErrors      = 1 << 1
};
typedef NSUInteger LoggerLogs;
```

And what I'd like to do is use `LoggerLogs` in my logic when determining whether or not it should be logged. So in my `log:(NSString *)message` I want it to log ONLY if the user set `LoggerLogMessages`, and for `logError:(NSString *)error` I want it to log ONLY if the user set `LoggerLogErrors`..
I know how to set them:

```
LoggerLogs logs = LoggerLogMessages | LoggerLogErrors;
```

What I don't know how to do is check if `LoggerLogMessages` or `LoggerLogErrors` is checked.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure this is answered here somewhere, but since I don't know the terms to use, it's really hard to search for >_<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)log:(NSString *)message {
    if (logs & LoggerLogMessages) {
        NSLog(@"message: %@", message);
    }
}

- (void)logError:(NSString *)error {
    if (logs & LoggerLogErrors) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }
}
```

Both `<<` and `&` are called *bitwise operators*.  If you google `bitwise operators C`, you'll find lots of explanations.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :-D It works. I should have known that.. I've just got the worst memory when it comes to terminology, ever.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the bitwise AND operator, `&`.

```
if (logs & LoggerLogMessages) {
  ...
}

if (logs & LoggerLogErrors) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if a flag is set, you just simply perform a *bitwise AND* (`&`) with the variable storing the flags with the flag being checked, the result will be that of the flag being checked if that bit sequence is contained within the variable:

```
if ( (logs & LoggerLogMessages) == LoggerLogMessages ) {
    // LoggerLogMessages is set
}
```

Or you might simply just have:

```
if (logs & LoggerLogMessages) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if you should log messages, use bitwise AND

```
if(logFlags & LoggerLogMessages)
    //log the message
```

Similarly if you want to log error messages

```
if(logFlags & LoggerLogErrors)
    //log the message
```

Also, the common term for these are [bit fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) or [flags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a logical-or of bitwise-ands, like:

```
if ((flag & LoggerLogMessages) || (flag & LoggerLogErrors))
```

Another thing to realize is that the two states you care about are the only two and both > 0, so

```
if (flag)
```

will work too.

Comment: `typedef` doesn't *have* to go before the `enum`.

Comment: try it in your compiler.  it needs a typedef if he wants to use it like a type.

Comment: @danh: No, OP is doing it [the way Apple recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004247-CH4-SW8).

Comment: @Josh: I see.  Thanks for the tip.  And I was responding to the wrong part of his question.  I edited the reply accordingly.